# Difference between REVOKE and RESTRICT in Datastax Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

What is the difference between REVOKE and RESTRICT CQLSH command in DSE.

Example: Keyspace Cycling has 2 tables - cycled and peddled respectively. and a role Jane exist
Jane is granted SELECT permission to all the keyspaces using below command
grant select on keyspace Cycling to 'jane';

But while revoking access for table cycled , it gives a warning and the permission is not revoed.
REVOKE select on cycling.cycled from 'jane';

Warning: Role jane was not granted SELECT on

Though the above revoke command gave a warning and not an error, still the role jane was able to access the data on table cycled, which means the select permission was not revoked.

The below restrict command worked as expected
RESTRICT select on cycling.cycled TO 'jane' ;

I would like to understand why the revoke command did not work at the table level.

DSE version : 6.8.23

Answer (score 0):

Did you find if there is any corresponding warnings/errors at `[debug|system].log` file?

It is important to understand what each command's role are here.

##### `RESTRICT`

Use `RESTRICT` to deny access to a role on a data resource, that is a keyspace or table. Restrict denies access even if permission to access the resource has been granted or inherited. `RESTRICT` permission always take precedence over `GRANT` permissions.

##### `REVOKE`

Removes privileges on database objects from a role.

##### Concept

When the role `jane` was granted `SELECT` permissions on `ALL KEYSPACES` via the below grant,

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL KEYSPACES TO jane;
```

via inheritance, `jane` got `SELECT` access to all tables under all keyspaces.

When you did add the restriction, it takes precedence and prevented the role `jane` to select/read from `cycling` table.

Comment: @Madhanvan There were no errors or warning seen in the system/debug log.
I understood the concept of restrict, but should the revoke command be working as well, if I am trying to revoke the access granted though it is inherited from my previous grant command. Just trying to understand why the revoke did not work

Comment: Doc references: [`REVOKE`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/dse/docs/reference/cql-commands/revoke.html) & [`RESTRICT`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/dse/docs/reference/cql-commands/restrict.html)